# Using Eulers Polyhedron Formula to show that the following statement is not true

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

We divide a piece of paper in 12 parts. Moreover we have 30 pieces of cellotape. We connect two pieces of paper, if they have a common "borderline".

Show that the following Statement is ***not*** true:

" 30 pieces of cellotape aren't enough to fix the paper. "

My work:

In order to better understand the situation I visualise the situation.

[image]

This would be an example for 4 pieces of paper and 4 cellotapes. So how can I Show that the Statement above is not true? My idea was to use Euler's polyhedron Formula.

$$ V - E + F = 2 $$ where $V$ is verticles, $E$ is edges and $F$ faces.
I would say that $F$ is 12 ( pieces of paper ) and $E$ is 30 ( cellotapes ). Now I'm stucked.

Comment: Consider the case where you don't tear the paper. Do you have $F=1$, $E=0$? A polyhedron is closed, but a piece of paper isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a classical fact that will be useful for this problem:

Definition: A maximal planar graph is one where every face is a triangle. In other words, we cannot add any edges.

Fact: A maximal planar graph on $n$ vertices can have at most $3n - 6$ edges.

Proof: We have the relation $3F = 2E$, since if we count the edges by adding $3$ per face each edge will be counted exactly twice. That is, $F = 2E/3$. Substituting into $V - E + F = 2$, we have $V  - E + 2E/3 = 2$, so $V - E/3 = 2$, so $3V - 6= E$.